# Is the constructor or setLayoutParams() that takes two integers in Android in px or dip?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been going through tutorials, and have been trying to understand some things, but I am a little confused about this statement:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
```

The Doc says width and height (meaning the two 85's), or how its displayed on the screen. But is that the same as doing this in a grid view in an xml file?

```
<GridView
    android:layout_height="85"
...
```

Doesn't seem right to me, which is why I ask. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs:

```
Parameters
width  the width, either MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT or a fixed size in pixels 
height  the height, either MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT or a fixed size in pixels 
weight  the weight
```

So, in pixels.

In the XML you can specify the units.